# C++ OpenCV Reading HaarCascades Slowing Down Computer

Tags: c++, xml, opencv

I'm writing a program using C++ and OpenCV. It's actually my first so what I'm asking is probably something very basic I've overlooked. Much of it is copied - not copy+pasted mind you, but copied by hand, going line by line, understanding what each line was doing as I wrote it - from some of OpenCV's tutorials. I'll paste the code below.

The problem I'm encountering is that as soon as the webcam starts trying to implement facial recognition, everything just SLOWS. DOWN. As I understand it, its because the .exe is trying to read from two MASSIVE .xml files every frame update, but I don't have any idea how to fix it. It was worse before I constrained the height, width, and framerate of the video.

If anyone has any ideas at this point, I'd love to hear them. I'm very new to software programming - until now I've mostly done web development, so I'm not used to worrying about system memory and other factors.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here are my system specs: Mac, OSX 10.9.4, 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5, 4 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 RAM.

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

/** Function Headers */
void detectAndDisplay( Mat frame );

/** Global variables */
String face_cascade_name = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
String eyes_cascade_name = "haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml";
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
CascadeClassifier eyes_cascade;
String window_name = "Capture - Face detection";

/** @function main */
int main( void )
{
    cv::VideoCapture capture;
    Mat frame;

    //-- 1. Load the cascades
    if( !face_cascade.load( face_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading face cascade\n"); return -1; };
    if( !eyes_cascade.load( eyes_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading eyes cascade\n"); return -1; };

    //-- 2. Read the video stream
    capture.open( -1 );
    if ( ! capture.isOpened() ) { printf("--(!)Error opening video capture\n"); return -1; }

    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,640);
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480);
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 15);

    while ( capture.read(frame) )
    {
        if( frame.empty() )
        {
            printf(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!");
            break;
        }

        //-- 3. Apply the classifier to the frame
        detectAndDisplay( frame );

        int c = waitKey(10);
        if( (char)c == 27 ) { break; } // escape
    }
    return 0;
}

/** @function detectAndDisplay */
void detectAndDisplay( Mat frame )
{
    std::vector<Rect> faces;
    Mat frame_gray;

    cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );
    equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray );

    //-- Detect faces
    face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
    {
        Point center( faces[i].x + faces[i].width/2, faces[i].y + faces[i].height/2 );
        ellipse( frame, center, Size( faces[i].width/2, faces[i].height/2 ), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 );

        Mat faceROI = frame_gray( faces[i] );
        std::vector<Rect> eyes;

        //-- In each face, detect eyes
        eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale( faceROI, eyes, 1.1, 2, 0 |CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );

        for ( size_t j = 0; j < eyes.size(); j++ )
        {
            Point eye_center( faces[i].x + eyes[j].x + eyes[j].width/2, faces[i].y + eyes[j].y + eyes[j].height/2 );
            int radius = cvRound( (eyes[j].width + eyes[j].height)*0.25 );
            circle( frame, eye_center, radius, Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ), 4, 8, 0 );
        }
    }
    //-- Show what you got
    imshow( window_name, frame );
}
```

Comment: I never had this problem. What are the specs of your computer?

Comment: Mac, OSX 10.9.4, 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5, 4 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 RAM (also edited in the main body of the question).

Comment: Hum, it takes usually about 2sec to load both haarcascades and you have a great computer.

Comment: You're right - and I actually had Activity Monitor open during my latest test. It showed the test app only using 6% CPU and nowhere near enough RAM to be causing this problem. And yet, for some reason, as soon as I run the .exe, the whole computer slows down, as though the .exe is sucking up ALL the CPU, even though the Activity Monitor indicates otherwise.

Comment: Why do you have a .exe on Mac?

Comment: Not sure what else I should be exporting to, and I can run a .exe from terminal. Might that be the problem? Should I be exporting to a different extension?

Comment: .exe are Windows executables. Unix and Linux executables have no extension. Are you using Xcode and the OpenCV Mac OS libraries? Aren't you using a Virtual Machine?

Comment: I'm not using a virtual machine, no. I've been working out of Terminal, using g++ and cmake to compile.

Comment: So I double-checked - I was away from the computer - and it actually is a unix executable, not a windows executable. I'm just so used to windows I assumed it was a .exe - but it's not actually!

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution would be to replace:

```
eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale( faceROI, eyes, 1.1, 2, 0 |CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );
```

by

```
eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale( faceROI, eyes, 1.3, 2, 0 |CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(60, 60), Size(350, 350) );
```

1.3 is the scale factor, Size(60, 60) the min windows size and Size(350, 350) the max one. It means basically that it will start to search for 60*60 faces then increase size by oldWindowSize*1.3 until it reach 350*350. It is assumed there that your faces are min 60*60 and max 350 * 350.

You can tune it even more depending what you want. The minSize will have a the most impact on performance as well as scale (but 1.3 is already high). The maxSize will have less impact.

After this update, your prog should be twice faster or decrease CPU usage by half. However, I am still surprise that with your current tunings and you computer you have performances problems...

Give us a feedback if it works.